# class="modal-dialog " style="padding-top: 20px; !important" - did not work

Tags: css

did not work:

```
 class="modal-dialog " style="padding-top: 20px; !important"
```

I would like it to be placed in the middle of the window
in the bootstrap.css file I was overwriting the css class but it did not help:

```
.modal-dialog {
  padding-top: 20px; !important
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  margin: 10px; }
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. Please create a [mcve], so that we can reproduce the issue you're having.

Comment: Changing `padding-top: 20px; !important` to `padding-top: 20px !important;`

Comment: @VicJordan  the window is still attached to the top of the page. It is not in the middle of the page

Comment: You have added one extra ; mark before !important. Secondly, !important makes your css rules hard to read, should avoid using it whenever possible.

Comment: works, the css file was overwritten

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **bootstrap 4** then use

`class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered"`

instead of

`class="modal-dialog"`

and for **bootstrap 3** use CSS

```
.modal { display: flex; } 
.modal .modal-dialog { margin: auto; }
```

***See this [link](https://dotdev.co/vertically-centered-bootstrap-modal/) for vertical centred bootstrap modal***

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged. You should summarise the linked article applying it to the question as posed. By all means provide links as sources and support for code you provide in your answers.

Comment: You should [edit that into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51606240/edit), not add it as a comment.